# Coefficient of determination is different between scikit-learn and scipy libraries. why?

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, statistics

I have a dataset from a paper and I am having a hard time verifying their reported coefficient of determination, R-squared. I used sklearn and scipy libraries and im getting different answers. why? which one is more reliable?
p.s. when I used Excel as another alternative I got the same answer as from scipy.

Below is the code I used to compare the results from SKlearn and Scipy:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

data = pd.read_csv("output.csv", header=None)

y_measured = data.iloc[0, :].values
y_predicted = data.iloc[1, :].values

print(r2_score(y_measured, y_predicted)) # prints 0.708717556205

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(y_measured, y_predicted)

print(r_value**2)  # prints 0.731889173485
```

Answer (score 6):

[`r2_score`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html) computes its value from the given *y* values and the *y* values predicted by the linear regression line, not from the given *x* and *y* values.

Here's an example.  First, the imports:

```
In [59]: import numpy as np

In [60]: from scipy import stats

In [61]: from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
```

Some data to work with:

```
In [62]: x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13])

In [63]: y = np.array([1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.7, 2.0, 4.1, 6.6])
```

Do the linear regression using [`scipy.stats.linregress`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html), and check *r*<sup>2</sup>:

```
In [64]: slope, intercept, rvalue, pvalue, stderr = stats.linregress(x, y)

In [65]: rvalue**2
Out[65]: 0.9485915175891462
```

For the given `x` values, compute the `y` values predicted by the regression line:

```
In [66]: ypred = slope*x + intercept
```

Compute *r*<sup>2</sup> again, using `r2_score`:

```
In [67]: r2_score(y, ypred)
Out[67]: 0.9485915175891464
```

As expected, we get the same value.

We can also compute this value with [`scipy.stats.pearsonr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html):

```
In [68]: pearson_r, pearson_p = stats.pearsonr(x, y)

In [69]: pearson_r**2
Out[69]: 0.9485915175891464
```

Comment: Thank you. I think it's the other way around: r2_score of sklearn calculates the reliable and true r2 value based on the definition of r2 while the other ones calculate the squared correlation coefficient. In a linear least squares regression with an intercept term and a single explanator, this is also equal to the squared Pearson correlation coefficient of the dependent variable y and explanatory variable x. Therefore, if you are using values obtained from linear least squares regression you may use both but when you are using other forms of regression r2_score is the correct function to use.